Deriving classical trajectories from quantum mechanics
A paper [1] by David Wallace contains a brief description of how classical trajectories emerge from quantum mechanics. I've summarised the relevant parts below:
Wallace says that decoherence lets us write a quantum system $|\psi\rangle$ in the following form:
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle = \int dq \, dp \, \alpha(q, p; t) |q,p\rangle |\varepsilon(q,p)\rangle
\tag{1}
$$
Here, $|q,p\rangle$ denote the state of a particle localised around the phase-space point $(q,p)$. The environment states $|\varepsilon(q,p)\rangle$ satisfy $\langle \varepsilon(q', p') | \varepsilon(q,p) \rangle \simeq 0$ unless $q \simeq q'$ and $p \simeq p'$. Wallace then mentions that this leads to the classical phase space evolution rule for $|\alpha(q,p,t)|^2$:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} |\alpha(q,p;t)|^2 \simeq \frac{\partial H}{\partial q} \frac{\partial |\alpha(q,p;t)|^2}{\partial p} - \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}\frac{\partial |\alpha(q,p;t)|^2}{\partial q}
\tag{2}
$$
where $H(q,p)$ is the Hamiltonian for the system. (Presumably this is the classical Hamiltonian, i.e. the quantum Hamiltonian "without the hats".)
Question: Are there any specific resources which derive equations (1) and (2)? So far I've had a look at Zurek's review [2] and Schlosshauer's book [3]. While they discuss related concepts such as Wigner's function and position-space localisation, they don't seem directly relevant to the equations I listed. (Unless I'm just overlooking something?)
References:
[1]: Decoherence and Ontology, or: How I Learned To Stop Worrying And Love FAPP
[2]: Decoherence, einselection, and the quantum origins of the classical
[3]: Decoherence and the Quantum-To-Classical Transition

Zurek's later decoherence paper from 2003 seems to contain the relevant equations, with the notation $w=|\alpha(q,p,t)|^2$. They are equations 24-25 and the immediately preceding discussion explains them. Zurek writes things in terms of the Wigner function, but it seems to me that his analysis translates to the wave function version, since $\int dp W(x,p) = |\psi (x,t)|^2$.

If you look at Section III.C.1 the author mentions Ehrenfest's theorem, which states that the expectation values of quantities like position and momentum match the expectation values of classical physics, see
https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Quantum_Mechanics/Introductory_Quantum_Mechanics_(Fitzpatrick)/03%3A_Fundamentals_of_Quantum_Mechanics/3.04%3A_Ehrenfest's_Theorem
This result isn't sufficient to explain the absence of interference in the objects you see around you and so doesn't explain the classical limit of quantum theory. If quantum theory predicts that I diffract while walking through a doorway the expectation value of my position might match that of classical physics but it wouldn't match reality.
What has to be explained to get a good approximation to classical equations of motion for the objects you see around from quantum theory is the suppression of interference. Decoherence is used to explain the suppression of interference. Wigner functions are useful for characterising the degree of interference, which is why they are often used in papers about decoherence as discussed in the reference provided in the answer above:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0306072
There are papers that more explicitly discuss recovering classical equations of motion such as Halliwell's papers about decoherence of local densities
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0305084
